# How to calculate how many bits in a decimal number is 1?

Tags: assembly, riscv, hammingweight, population-count

This program I created in RISC-V RARS 1.3 application is designed to take a decimal number and count how many bits are in that number.  The one I am testing is the decimal number 5, and this program should work for any positive number I put on t1.  Here is the code I created.  The program is meant to add one counter whenever the result of the AND function is not 0, but the problem I have is that the program does not stop.  Is there a solution to this problem?

```
_start:

li t1,2 # start with decimal 5, binary 101
li t2,1 # adding counter for AND function
li t3,0 # bit counter count
li t4,0 # to compare 0

and t5,t1,t2 # t1 & t2 = t5
bne t5,t4,label # go to label if t5 != 0
beqz t5,label2 # go to label if t5 == 0

label:
addi t3,t3,1 # add one to bit count
slli t2,t2,1 # shift left
and t5,t1,t2 # t1 & new t2 = t5
bne t5,t4,label # go to label if t5 != 0
beqz t5,label2 # go to label if t5 == 0

label2:
slli t2,t2,1 # shift left
and t5,t1,t2 # t1 & new t2 = t5

.data
```

Comment: Can you write this in C first?  It is so much harder to develop algorithms in assembly when you don't yet know assembly language.  I recommend C because you can verify that the C version works with some simple testing (translating a broken algorithm can be very painful to debug at the assembly level).  Once you have a working C algorithm, then translate that into assembly literally, variable for variable, and line of code for line of code, without trying to make improvements during translation.

Comment: `li t1,2 # start with decimal 5`  - nope, `li t1, 2` puts the decimal number `2` into the register, `0...00010`.  Obviously your algorithm is broken, too, but it's not a good start when the first thing in your code doesn't match the comments.

Comment: RISC-V has an always-zero register x0.  You don't need to load `0` into another register to compare against.  https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/risc-v/registers.  You also don't need `bne` and `beqz`, just `beqz label2` or fall through into the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Since you start with `t2 = 1` and multiply it by `2` in each iteration, you should stop the calculation once the value of `t2` becomes greater than `t1`.

Also, in your code, I see you that you probably intended to handle two cases:

1. `label:` - this block handles the case when the current bit tested is 1, it increments the number of bits and then jumps to either `label` or `label2`. Here, you just need to add the exit condition as mentioned above
2. `label2:` - this block handles the case when the current bit tested is 0, it does not change the number of bits, but it also does not seem to continue with either `label` or `label2`. I think that is should keep looking whether there are any higher 1 bits, until the exit condition `t2>t1` is reached.

Answer (score 0):

If RISC-V doesn't have an instruction that counts the number of set bits efficiently (most other CPUs do now); then the next best approach is like:

```
    // Value is 32 pieces with 1 bit per piece

    temp1 = (value & 0x555555555) + (value & 0xAAAAAAAA) >> 1;

    // Temp1 is 16 pieces with 2 bits per piece

    temp2 = (temp1 & 0x33333333) + (temp1 & 0xCCCCCCCC) >> 2;

    // Temp2 is 8 pieces with 4 bits per piece

    temp3 = (temp2 & 0x0F0F0F0F) + (temp2 & 0xF0F0F0F0) >> 4;

    // Temp3 is 4 pieces with 8 bits per piece

    temp4 = (temp3 & 0x00FF00FF) + (temp3 & 0xFF00FF00) >> 8;

    // Temp4 is 2 pieces with 16 bits per piece

    result = (temp4 & 0x0000FFFF) + (temp2 & 0xFFFF0000) >> 16;

    // Result is the count of all bits that were set in value (or, sum of all 32 of the original 1-bit values)
```

I have no idea how to write this in RISC-V assembly (I'd compile it then cut&paste the resulting assembly, but don't have a compiler for RISC-V either).

Comment: On machines with a fast multiply, you can horizontal sum bytes in a 32 or 64-bit integer with one multiply and a right shift, as explained in [How to count the number of set bits in a 32-bit integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/109023)  That also optimizes the first step to use a `sub` and only mask once, using `i = i - ((i >> 1) & 0x55555555);`.

Comment: For the later operations, you still only need one mask per step (big advantage on a RISC where each 32-bit value has to be constructed separately with 2 instructions).  Shift *before* masking, like `t2 = (t1 & 0x33..33) + ((t1>>2) & 0x33..33)`.  Unlike x86 or AArch64, you can't just use each mask as an immediate for an AND instruction.  Even constructing one mask from the other with a shift would cost extra instructions because you still have to right-shift the result before adding.